# Custom msbuild task tries to load dependency with wrong version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have custom publish process which firstly merges some assemblies into one via ILRepack, then performs some other steps and finally cleans up publish directory - removes merged dependencies from APP_NAME.deps.json, relevant assemblies and symbol files.

In order to implement the last step, I've created a NuGet package with a custom MsBuild task. 
According to [Nate's blog post](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/07/05/msbuild-task-in-nuget/), I've set `PrivateAssets="All"` in order to ship all task's dependencies within the package:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="2019.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="15.9.20" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Update="@(PackageReference)" PrivateAssets="All" />        
</ItemGroup>
```

Package layout looks like:

[image]

Suddenly, during publish, this step fails with error:

> task failed unexpectedly. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. Could not find or load a specific
>   file. (0x80131621)

**I can't understand why task tries to load version 12.0.0.0 while I have Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2 (as specified in PackageReference).**

Thank you for any help!

---

Updated:

According to this [msbuild spec](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/specs/task-isolation-and-dependencies.md) currently MSBuild tasks have serious limitations:

> Tasks in MSBuild are dynamically loaded assemblies with potentially separate and colliding dependency trees. Currently MSBuild on .NET Core has no isolation between tasks and as such only one version of any given assembly can be loaded. Prime example of this is Newtonsoft.Json which has multiple versions, but all the tasks must agree on it to work.

Comment: 12.0.2 is the NuGet package version, while 12.0.0.0 is the assembly version. I don't think there is something wrong with the version numbers, but elsewhere. Also if you do merge assemblies to create a single executable, .NET Core 3.0 and above already have built-in support so your customization can be removed.

Comment: I've looked at used MSBuild version's deps.json and found dependency on "Newtonsoft.Json": "11.0.1". When I aligned my version to this one task completes successfully. Seems like it's an existing limitation: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7510. Now I guess the better way in such situations is to use build tool instead: https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/11/11/build-tools-in-nuget/

Comment: I like to subclass Andrew Arnott's `ContextAwareTask` which creates an assembly load context on core or an app domain on full framework MSBuild which then allows me to ship all my task dependencies - simplified fork at https://github.com/dasMulli/AssemblyInfoGenerationSdk/blob/master/src/DasMulli.AssemblyInfoGeneration.Sdk/ContextAwareTask.cs

Comment: though on full framework, deriving from AppDomainIsolatedTask (msbuild) may still be necessary (with an additional #if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) mentioned in the comment, 12.0.2 is the NuGet package version which corresponds to the 12.0.0.0 assembly version. So the system attempts to load the right version of the assembly.
2. According to [task-isolation-and-dependencies.md](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/specs/task-isolation-and-dependencies.md), [related issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7510) etc. custom MsBuild tasks have serious limitations.
3. MsBuild itself includes a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1, so custom tasks can't load any other version of this dependency.

Workarounds:

1. Use the same dependency version as MsBuild. I guess this approach is fragile and should not be used.
2. Create and package console application instead of a custom MsBuild task. I've chosen this approach because it is easily extensible and allows us to use any dependency version. [Nate's blog post](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/11/11/build-tools-in-nuget/) gives an overview of the approach.
3. As [Martin Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784387/martin-ullrich) mentioned in the comment, we could use task with isolation boundaries. [ContextAwareTask.cs](https://github.com/dasMulli/AssemblyInfoGenerationSdk/blob/master/src/DasMulli.AssemblyInfoGeneration.Sdk/ContextAwareTask.cs) demonstrates the approach.

Comment: Hi metacube, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)